# Maximum concurrent http connections to the same host in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, httprequest

Does it make sense to have an `async.reduce` if all I do in the iterator function is an http-request to the same host (+ scraping in the request's callback)? I'm asking because the maximum TCP connections to the same host at one time seems to be one (i.e by using `console.log` in my code, it seems it is only after the scraping finishes in one iteration, that another http-request is made, regardless of how long it takes to receive a response from the web server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. I didn't know that `async.reduce` processes the iterations in series, not in parallel.

Source: https://github.com/caolan/async#reducearr-memo-iterator-callback